# Blocked by CORS policy in Chrome after enabling CORS for Lambda Function?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, rest, cors, aws-amplify

I've enabled CORS in the console for a Lambda function following [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html).

The API is also an express server that enables CORS for all methods:

```
// Enable CORS for all methods
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
  next()
});
```

However the browser is still blocking the request because it is not receiving the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.  This is the complete message:

> home:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://szxjza7hz5.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/loco/myendpoint' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How do we trouble shoot this?

The testing approach in the instructions provide a curl command like this:

```
curl -v -X OPTIONS -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" -H "Origin: http://localhost:4200" https://szxjza7hz5.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/loco
```

However this fails due to a missing authentication token:

```
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 403 
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 42
< date: Wed, 19 Feb 2020 01:45:47 GMT
< x-amzn-requestid: a529894d-19ff-4c95-915b-45c4098d30ea
< x-amzn-errortype: MissingAuthenticationTokenException
< x-amz-apigw-id: IHvz3Fp_IAMF43g=
< x-cache: Error from cloudfront
< via: 1.1 58e86c1faaee1b15c90e95d794e240dd.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-cf-pop: ORD51-C3
< x-amz-cf-id: jyTAo6OUrhUWWVNOSdk6M0384K515YzE0V9Vgg-WhfXXkLDzLofr9Q==
< 
* Connection #0 to host szxjza7hz5.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com left intact
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding these fields to response header:

```
const response = {
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true,
    },
    body: "...",
    statusCode: 200
}
```

You could also experience the same error if not redeploy the API after updating it. Try to redeploy it as below:

[image]

Comment: I think perhaps the problem is that `Amplify push` is not updating the new endpoints that I added and which I was testing.  I asked another question about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60292679/how-to-add-an-additional-endpoint-to-the-aws-amplify-express-server

Comment: I just accepted this answer since it's a good one.  Put an additional answer with my notes in it.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in running an update to the API.  I thought that if I added another endpoint to the express server `amplify push` would pick it up and deploy it.

We need to run `amplify update API` in order to create a new endpoint.  So when I was making the API call against the endpoint I thought was there, it was not passing the preflight check because there was not endpoint ...

Comment: "We need to run amplify update API in order to create a new endpoint. "=> I am having the same issue, I ran the "amplify update api" command but I have the same issue. I am not sure what you mean by "create a new endpoint". In my case, the endpoint is the same, it is just changed internally.

Comment: @AjitGoel did you find a solution for this??  I have the exact same issue that my endpoint hasn't changed but now I get the CORS error

Comment: @VikG, I was able to workaround the problem by updating the lambda function and\or re-creating a new api pointing to the same function.