# How to add an additional endpoint to the AWS Amplify Express Server?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, rest, express, aws-amplify

I've generated an REST express server with Amplify.

I tried adding to more endpoints to it:

```
// using serverless express
app.post('/myendpoint', function(req, res) {
  console.log('body: ', req.body)
  res.json(req.body)
});

// using serverless express
app.get('/myendpoint', function(req, res) {
  res.json({success: 'get call to my endpoint succeed!', url: req.url});
});
```

After running `amplify push` I don't see these endpoints in the console, and I can't make requests to them via amplify.

The endpoints that were generated as part of the initial configuration work.

What is the correct way to add more REST endpoints?  I have a feeling that I'm missing some additional configuration step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After deploy the API and function, to add additional path you should use "amplify update api"

Comment: Cool - It looks like we need one express server per path?  In other words if we generate a path `/items` then we can have an express server for that path.  If we need another path `/customers` then we need a new express server for that path.  Does that sound correct?

Comment: amplify api update apiName  and then add a new path, add a new route in your existing serverless app which exists in a lambda function or if it's getting bulky, put it in its own function within the same API.

Answer (score 1):

As Kevin Le stated running "amplify update api" will allow you to add another "root" path such as "/items" or "/customers", but I have been running into problems adding nested paths such as "/customer/addAddress" after the initial api creation.

What I have tried:

1. I can add them during the initial creation of the API, but not during an update
2. I can change the cloud formation template to include them in the API gateway, but any calls to the nested path are picked up by the root paths proxy.
3. I can add them in the express lambda function ( defeats the purpose of API Gateway )

They need to add a few enhancements to amplify rest API so we can take advantage of the API Gateway.  It's not truly serverless until we can separate functions for GET, POST, PUT, etc.

UPDATE:  I wanted to follow up after futher investigation.  A solution I found is to remove the "root" path's {proxy} endpoint in the cloud formation file for the API gateway.  The file should be located at:  "project root"/amplify/backend/api/"api name"/"api name"-cloudformation-template.json.  Then remove the path located at Resources->"api name"->Properties->Body->paths->"api name"/{proxy+}.

FURTHER INVESTIGATION:  I have not tried this yet, but the order of the path's in the cloud formation file might have an affect on how the requests are processed, so if you move the "root" proxy to the last path, you might not have to remove it.  Also thanks to Piotr for fixing my poor grammar!

Answer (score 0):

You can run "amplify update api"
then choose to add a new endpoint
and choose assign new(old) lambda function for this endpoint